# unable to write multiple strings into an excel using poi data driven, but i can write each cell by mentioning row and column number

Tags: java, automation, apache-poi, data-driven-tests

I do have multiple strings so i would like to write those all string values into excel without giving any row and column numbers statically.dynamically it has to set data row by row in excel, do you have any snippet code to write huge data into excel it will be help full for me.

```
public void VerifyToWriteTaxValues() throws IOException {
    String valueEI = processpay.taxesEIvalue.getAttribute("value");
    String valueQPIP = processpay.taxesQPIPvalue.getAttribute("value");
    String valuecpp = processpay.taxesCPPvalue.getAttribute("value");
    String valueQPP = processpay.taxesQPPvalue.getAttribute("value");
    String valueIT = processpay.taxesITvalue.getAttribute("value");
    String valueQTax = processpay.taxesQTAXvalue.getAttribute("value");

    excel.setCellData(path, "compare_Calculatepay_to_YTD", 1, 6, valueEI);
    excel.setCellData(path, "compare_Calculatepay_to_YTD", 1, 7, valueQPIP);
    excel.setCellData(path, "compare_Calculatepay_to_YTD", 1, 8, valuecpp);
    excel.setCellData(path, "compare_Calculatepay_to_YTD", 1, 9, valueQPP);
    excel.setCellData(path, "compare_Calculatepay_to_YTD", 1, 10, valueIT);
    excel.setCellData(path, "compare_Calculatepay_to_YTD", 1, 11, valueQTax);
}
```

here it is excel setdata code

```
    public String setCellData(String xlfile,String xlsheet,int rownum,int 
    colnum,String data) {
    try {
    fi=new FileInputStream(xlfile);
    wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fi);

    ws=wb.getSheet(xlsheet);
    row=ws.getRow(rownum);
    if(row==null) {
    row=ws.createRow(rownum);
    }
    cell=row.getCell(colnum,Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
    if(cell==null) {
    cell=row.createCell(colnum);
    cell.setCellValue(data);
    }else {
        cell.setCellValue(data);
    }
    fo=new FileOutputStream(xlfile);
    wb.write(fo);       
    wb.close();
    fi.close();
    fo.close();
    return data;
    }catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("The set data exception is"+e);




    return data;
     }
    }
```

here i am able to set into one cell mentioning row number and column number,further it will become lengthy i can't mention every time row and column number.can you provide some code snippet

this i have tried to store elements in list but in excel it fills list of 
  elements into one cell

```
String[] taxvalues= {valueEI,valueQPIP,valuecpp,valueQPP,valueIT,valueQTax};
  List<String> list=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(taxvalues));
  System.out.println("list of tax values are:"+list);
  String str=list.toString();
  for(int row=1;row<=6;row++) {
  for(int column=1;column<=1;column++) {
  String writeEI = excel.setCellData(path,"Sheet4", row, column,str);
  }
  }
```

see the attached excelsheet image,[there C column format of data has to set in each cell, but in B column as per above code it setting data in excel, iam excepting C column type of fields plz help i think it wont workout through list since we stored in list and that list is printing in each cell as B column as iam excepting to write string values As per C column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsy9J.png)

Comment: add everything to a list and loop over the list. If you need to fill rows as well as columns, create a `Map` and iterate over it

Comment: hi XtremeBaumer, i have made list to store all elements it has stored but coming to excel it is filling all elements in one cell i have used for loop  for rows and columns

Comment: well, you pass the same string over and over to different cells. You need a new string from the list for every cell